# MVC 4 EF 5 Code First and deploying to azure cause twice seeding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, dbcontext

I am trying to add my website with database created by entity framework code first to azure. Everything seems ok but data which I had in Seed I have twice. I tried to wrote steps which I did:

- I enabled and added first migration.
- I set update-database
- I added downloaded publish profile
- I check all possibilities in option with datacontext a from listpicker I choose right connection string
- I publish it

I think these are right steps how to do it. But in my local database is everything all right but in azure there is everything twice. So how can I fix it?

Configuration with Seed:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ObedoveMenuContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(ObedoveMenuContext context)
    {
        var cities = new List<City>
            {
            new City() { Name = "ExampleCity" },
            new City() { Name = "ExampleCity2" },
        };
        cities.ForEach(c => context.Cities.AddOrUpdate(c));
        ...
    }
 }
```

and my context:

```
public class ObedoveMenuContext : DbContext
{
    public ObedoveMenuContext() : base("name=ObedoveMenuContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Restaurant> Restaurants { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Meal> Meals { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ActionOffer> ActionOffers { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: have you tried deploying with just one role instance. And after application is run for first time (context initialization, seed, etc.)  scale out to 2 or more instances. I imagine your seed is executed for each role instance you have. Probably you'd have to implement some cross-instance synchronization logic to prevent multiple seeding.

Comment: how can I deploy with just one role instance? I have default RoleProvider and I didn't change this anyway. For now It's enought with just one role.

Comment: please read carefully [this blog post](http://blogs.staykov.net/2011/12/windows-azure-basics-part-1-of-n.html) to understand what is a `Role` and `RoleInstance` in the context of Windows Azure Cloud Services. And understand my question and comment!